# Android SQLite Update not working in background in AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

I have an interesting problem. I have a SQLite update that I am performing within a AsyncTask on Android (because I also have had to do a ton of remote calls before doing the DB call). The code works like a charm, unless the application is pushed to the background (eg, using the Home button). The task continues to work in the background successfully, the DB call is made and returns 1 row changed, but the data never actually makes it to the DB. No errors or exceptions. Even stranger, the logs show everything working just fine - no exceptions, nada.
Again, when NOT pushed to the background this works fine.

The call:

```
    result = (sqlDB.update("FormInstance", values, "InstanceId=?",  new String[] { String.valueOf(form.getSubmissionId()) }) > 0);
```

Also there is no transaction involved with this call (unless it is happening under the hood of the Android SQLite code).

Anyone know of why this might be the case? Is there something that happens to DB connections or SQLLite that I am unaware of when pushed to the backround?

**UPDATE**

I have tried wrapping the DB call with a begintransaction/endtrans without any success:

```
    sqlDB.beginTransaction();
    try {
        result = (sqlDB.update("FormInstance", values, "InstanceId=?",  new String[] { String.valueOf(form.getSubmissionId()) }) > 0);
    }
    finally {
        sqlDB.endTransaction();
    }
```

Still acts as though it was successful but data never committed.Please note that I pulled the DB from the device and verified that it had NOT been updated.

Comment: Sounds like your transaction is not commited at the end of the query. Have you tried to compile the query by yourself and do it between a transaction block?

Comment: @droidpl Sry- There is no transaction involved.

Comment: Everytime you do something in the database a transaction is created, although the update call make it behind the scenes. Can you do it with the implicit transaction to debug what is going on?

Comment: @droidpl Do you mean write an explicit begintran/commit around this update? I could...the funny thing is that this works fine unless the app is pushed to the background. I have tried to walkthru in debugger but it just ends up hanging.

Comment: @StephenMcCormick, how do you know that "the data never actually makes it to the DB"? I suspect that if `SQLiteDatabase#update()` returns value greater than 0 then the data did make it into DB, and the actual error is in the "observation" logic.

Comment: That is really weird. Also have you tested it in another device? Maybe it is something device related. Finally another option that could come to my mind is implement this in a service or content provider, to be honest I never saw something like this before.

Comment: @VasiliyGood point - I should have mentioned I pulled the DB off the device and looked inside at that row in the DB. The data had not been updated. But the logs show that the lines of code had been executed (I have wrapped all the questionable area in logging...just did not show that above.

Comment: @droidpl Yes it has been verified on multiple devices (in fact a customer originally reported it). It is down right strange...I'm sure I am probably doing something wrong, but maybe I have uncovered a DB/Android bug? I am running out of options. At this point I might just have to save the data before the task and then revert the data if the operation fails (rather than saving it at the end).

Comment: Is the code run within `doInBackground (Params... params)`? If not, that might explain it.

Comment: Turns out I can a complete fool. The code was actually working...but behind the scenes the OnPause was being called (which I did not log) which then did the same call with exact same data except it flipped the status back. Doh. So basically I was successfully setting the value, then it was being overwritten by OnPause, which only occurred when the device was shoved to the background. Thanks all who helped suffer thru my foolishness!

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I found that while there was a onPause method occasionally updating the data, the real problem was that the SQLLite update was not really updating one column (FormStatus) when the update was performed. This was only the case when running in the background. I verified this by querying the result immediately after the update. The final solution was a secondary update that only updated the FormStatus column, which did work. Wrapping with begintrans/endtrans did not help.